# Prove the existence of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to understand the abstract concepts of linear algebra trough this example and I'm not doing very good.

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space over som field $K$. Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces
>   of $V$ such that $dim(U) = dim(W)$. Prove there is such vector subspace $F$ of $V$ that $F\oplus W = F \oplus U = V$

First, I listed everything i know:

- Let $n$ be dimension of $V$
- Let $k$ ($k \le n $) be the dimension of $U$ and $W$
- Let $B_v = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be basis of $V$
- Let $B_u = \{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$ be basis of $U$
- Let $B_w = \{w_1,w_2,...,w_k\}$ be basis of $W$

I did solve this problem but I believe it is only a partial solution because it does not have to be true that $F \cap W = \{0\}$ ( here, 0 denotes the zero vector ). But of course, If i take $U=W$, i can form $F$ as 
$$F=L (B_v \backslash B_w) $$

But what happens when $U \ne W $ ? I'm trying to imagine the solution with diagrams in my head and i have a feeling the intersect of $W $ and $ U$ plays a major part in constructing $F$ but I can't grasp it..

Comment: I believe that the statement to be proved should be "$\exists F_1,F_2$ such that $U\oplus F_1=W\oplus F_2=V$", where $F_1,F_2$ need not necessarily be same.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay No, this is the exact statement on the task. There is only one subspace $F$ required for which the above needs to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Write $U=(U\cap W)\oplus U_1$ and $W=(U\cap W)\oplus W_1$. Suppose $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ is a basis of $U_1$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is a basis of $W_1$. Let $F_1$ be the linear span of $\{x_j=u_j+w_j: j=1,2,\ldots,m\}$. Show that $U+W=F_1\oplus U=F_1\oplus W$. If $U+W$ is a proper subspace of $V$, how to construct $F$ from $F_1$?

Comment: Coming back at this a year later, I chuckle at what I didn't know.